# Ionic $state.go not navigating to new view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use $state.go on a button ng-click event. No navigation occurs but I get the following error:

`Error: Could not resolve 'selectContacts' from state 'tab.settings'` I have used this before but not in a tabbed app, is that the problem? I feel like this will be a very simple fix but I am struggling to pin it down based on looking at the docs.

From controllers.js

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.goToContactsPage = function () {
        $state.go('selectContacts');
    }
})
```

From app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })

    .state('tab.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
            views: {
                'tab-settings': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
                    controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('selectContacts', {
        url: '/selectContacts',
         views: {
             'selectContacts': {
                 templateUrl: 'templates/selectContacts.html',
                 controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
             }
         }
     });
```

The button:

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="goToContactsPage()">Select Contacts</button>
```

Comment: This is a typo `.state(selectContacts'`  fix it.

Comment: would @Michelem's comment not be obvious when you load the app.js?  See the console.

Comment: Sorry, somehow just a typo in my question, this is not present in my code....oops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your `views` property in the route config.

```
views: {
   'selectContacts': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/selectContacts.html',
      controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
   }
}
```

I removed it and replace with this:

```
.state('selectContacts', {
      url: "/selectContacts",
      templateUrl: "templates/contact.html",
      controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
    });
```

Check this Codepen http://codepen.io/nampdn/pen/BoVweN